# How to convert array to multiple variables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, hash

I have an array:

```
$r = array(1,2,42,55);
```

and I want to call `encrypt();` function of [hashids](http://www.hashids.org/php/)

which takes input like this:

```
encrpyt(1,2,42,55);
```

I tried `extract($r)` but it does not work.

Comment: I suppose you should do the encrypt to the array values not the array !!

Comment: Yes, that's why I want to extract the values from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a callback on each of the elements of the array. check [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) if it helps.