# How to individually pass array values to a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to be able to use [HashIDs](http://hashids.org) in my project. 
With HashIDs you can create hash IDs from either one or n-number of integers, like so:

```
encrypt(1);
encrypt(1,2,3,4);
encrypt(1,2,...n);
```

This works fine for one variable already, but unfortunately I'm sometimes receiving a string of comma separated numbers that I'd wish to encode. So it would be "1,2,3,4,5".

Of course I can easily turn that into an array, but an array doesn't help, as I'd still need to pass the valuables individually to encrypt. And since I do not know how many integers there are in the string, I do not know how I can implement that.

Coincidentally, [PHP has a way for dealing with that exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802364/how-to-convert-array-to-multiple-variables-in-php).

How could I achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: I looked at the PHP solution and it looks like it's an array map function, have you looked at the JS [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap) yet?  And if you have a comma separated string, I think you could just `string.split(",");` to turn it into an array and then use the `.map()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split into an array and convert the values to integers, then use the [`Function.prototype.apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call your `encrypt()` passing the array values as arguments.

Here's a solution:

```
var myArgs = "1,2,3,4,5"; // etc.

myArgs = myArgs.split(",").map(function(i) {return parseInt(i);});
encrypt.apply(this, myArgs);
```

**Explaination:** the first line is just an assignment; the second line uses the `.split()` method to turn your string into an array of characters, which gets parsed into an array of integers using `.map(...)`; finally the third line uses the `.apply()` method to apply your array values as arguments of your function, and calls `encrypt(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);` like you want.

Comment: thanks for the hint, Marco. I do only seem to get the first number into myArgs on the third line of your example. myArgs after "myArgs = myArgs.split(",").map(parseInt);" looks like [1,Null,Null,...].

Comment: @dengar81 sorry, for that, I edited my code! Now it works fine.

Comment: Hi Marco, sure this all makes sense to me. However, I still have an issue on the apply method: I get the error message: "TypeError: Cannot find function _encode in object [object Object]."

Comment: @dengar81 that looks like an unrelated error. Perhaps your error is referring to a function that doesn't exist on the local object. By the way it seems unrelated, you should ask another question for that.

Comment: was just a minor typo. the function was called encrypt, not encode :D!

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the `arguments` object (it contains all the arguments passed to a function):

```
   function callEncrypt() {
       return this.apply(encrypt, arguments);
   }
```

Then you can use it with as many arguments as you want:

```
callEncrypt(1);
callEncrypt(1, 2);
callEncrypt(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: `this.apply(encrypt, arguments);` this is wrong, it will result in a type error saying "undefined is not a function", because you're calling the apply method of the `Window` object, which hasn't got it at all.

Comment: Plus, this still isn't of any help, because now using `callEncrypt` will result in the same problem the OP had before with `encrypt`...

Answer (score 0):

Pass the arguments using the [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
var myArgs = "1,2,3,4,5"; // etc.
myArgs = myArgs . split(',') . map(parseInt);

encrypt(...myArgs);
```

Comment: This is hasn't been implemented yet and fails in most of the current browsers, plus you would have to use strict mode on some browsers.

Comment: This answer was not intended to be a tutorial on ES6 and its toolings, but suffice it to say that there are a rich variety of ways to use ES6 in almost any environment. It's completely incorrect to say that it's not implemented. For instance, it's completely implemented in node. It's implemented in a well-known, well-supported transpiler called Babel, which fits perfectly well into a browser-based workflow. In any case, the intent of this answer was merely to point out the possibility for those who are looking forward as opposed to backward.

Comment: Actually I said *"hasn't been implemented yet and fails in most of the current browsers"*, so yes, I know it's implemented in *some* platforms, but, like I said, not in *all* the current browsers.

Comment: OK, let's beat a dead horse here. It does **not** fail in any current browser, because you transpile it into ES5 which all browsers support.